# Is it possible to install multiple boot linux OS's on a singular VM?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vmware, multiboot

I was asked to test the possibility of installing 4 discrete OS's (Centos: 7.7, 7.8, 8.0, Ubuntu 18.4.4) on one VMware machine. Thing is, I cannot get beyond installation of two systems. By the third one I cannot even get in to the first one installed, and it does not even appear in the efibootmgr list. I would be happy to get some kind of solution to this process. The VM's settings for this matter: EFI based 1X CPU RAM - 2 GB (Virtual) HDD - 80 GB

All ISO's are 64 bit

Thank you!

Comment: What's the point? What advantage do you have over installing multiple VMs?

Answer (score 0):

You can install as many OS'es in a virtual machine as humanly possible given you've got enough space for them. GPT allows to have 128 partitions, with LVM you've got even more freedom.

> By the third one I cannot even get in to the first one installed, and it does not even appear in the efibootmgr list.

Install them in this order: Centos: 7.7, 7.8, Ubuntu 18.4.4 and lastly CentOS 8.0. Then boot into CentOS 8.0 and run `sudo grub2-mkconfig > /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` and you'll be able to choose from any of them on boot.

Remember:

1. You'll need a system efi partition (300MB will be enough)
2. You'll need a common /boot partition (I'd allocate at least 1GB for it given your requirements)
3. As for root FS'es for the remaining OSes - you can split the rest of the space the way you need.